# Создание объекта, имеющего класс из переменной

Tags: java, рефлексия

Допустим, есть переменная типа `Class`, например, мы ее получили `Class t=a.getClass();`.
Как валидно создать объект данного класса?

Comment: Вы уже раскройте секрет любопытному: зачем вам таким образом создавать обьекты?

Comment: чтобы хранить эти объекты на харде и подгружать их оттуда относительно эффективно, т.к. их 2^15 штук))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего

```
t.newInstance();
```

Это если вам надо использовать конструктор без параметров. В обратом случае

```
t.getConstructor(f1, f2, ...).newInstance(x1, x2, ...);
```

где `f1, f2, ...` - классы параметров конструктора, а `x1, x2, ...` - значения параметров конструктора.

Учтите, что вам придется делать небезопасный каст, если ваша переменная `t` имеет сырой тип `Class`, а не типизированный, вроде `Class<Integer>`.

Comment: Спасибо!
Небезопасность меня не очень волнует - эти классы могут быть только потомками одного абстрактного класса, а если они вдруг не его потомки - гори все огнем)))
Кстати, может, подскажете, как сделать это красивее? Мне надо сохранять класс объекта в виде числа, а потом вытаскивать обратно.

Comment: Хм, это зависит от того, что вы понимаете под "числом". В каком-то смысле, классы в файлах `.class` тоже хранятся в одном большом "числе". А какова ваша цель?

Comment: есть соответствие класс-id, и по id надо получать класс. 
чем меньше id, тем лучше, дабы памяти жрало меньше

Comment: Какой памяти? Вы же все равно будете загружать класс в память? Непонятно. Говорю что-то по наитию, может, это то, что вы ищите: вы можете хранить строки вида `com.example.MyClass` и загружать классы через <a href="http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)">Class.forName()</a>.

Comment: нет, мне надо будет хранить где-то 2^15 таких Id в одном файле))
и таких файлов... имелась ввиду память на диске, а не оперативная.

Comment: Ну так сделайте конфиг, определяющий соответствие id и имён классов. Такой подход используется, например, в Oracle Coherence. И тогда можете сохранять id и используя мапу Map<Integer, Class<? extends ..>> получать потом по id класс и создавать экземпляр. Или испольщуйте Builder в более сложных случаях чтобы избежать newInstance по классу при каждом чтении и ускорить загрузку в случае проблем со скорости из-за reflections.

Comment: Конфиг-то я сделал)) Просто спрашивал, как это сделать элегантнее и производительнее. И своего добился))
Спасибо.